# What is the content of the app invite configuration file?

Tags: google-app-invites

I want to add [app-invite to an Android app](https://developers.google.com/app-invites/android/guides/app). This requires to add a configuration file. However, the page for creating that configuration doesn't finish loading. I've tried multiple browsers, on several days and a friend of mine had the same results.

What is the actual content of that configuration file? Can I create it myself, given that I know my package names and similar things?